# Time and Space complexity of Palindrome Partitioning II

Tags: python, time-complexity, space-complexity

So I was solving this LeetCode question - https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-partitioning-ii/ and have come up with the following most naive brute force recursive solution. Now, I know how to memoize this solution and work my way up to best possible with Dynamic Programming. But in order to find the time/space complexities of further solutions, I want to see how much worse this solution was and I have looked up in multiple places but haven't been able to find a concrete T/S complexity answer.

```
def minCut(s: str) -> int:
    def is_palindrome(start, end):
        while start < end:
            if not s[start] == s[end]:
                return False
            start += 1
            end -= 1
        return True

    def dfs_helper(start, end):
        if start >= end:
            return 0

        if is_palindrome(start, end):
            return 0
        curr_min = inf
        
        # this is the meat of the solution and what is the time complexity of this
        for x in range(start, end):
            curr_min = min(curr_min, 1 + dfs_helper(start, x) + dfs_helper(x + 1, end))
        return curr_min

    return dfs_helper(0, len(s) - 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at a worst case scenario, i.e. the palindrome check will not allow us to have an early out.

For writing down the recurrence relation, let's say n = end - start, so that n is the length of the sequence to be processed. I'll assume the indexed array accesses are constant time.

`is_palindrome` will check for palindromity in O(end - start) = O(n) steps.

`dfs_helper` for a subsequence of length n, calls `is_palindrome` once and then has 2n recursive calls of lengths 0 through n - 1, each being called two times, plus the usual constant overhead that I will leave out for simplicity.

So, we have

```
T(0) = 1
T(n) = O(n) + 2 * (sum of T(x) for x=0 to n-1)
# and for simplicity, I will just use
T(n) = n + 2 * (sum of T(x) for x=0 to n-1)
```

This pattern already [has to be at least exponential](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/530132). We can look at the next few steps:

```
T(1)  =   3 = 1 + 2 *  1  =  1 + 2 * (T(0))
T(2)  =  10 = 2 + 2 *  4  =  2 + 2 * (T(0) + T(1))
T(3)  =  31 = 3 + 2 * 14  =  3 + 2 * (T(0) + T(1) + T(2))
T(4)  =  94 = 4 + 2 * 45  =  4 + 2 * (T(0) + T(1) + T(2) + T(3))
```

which looks as if this grows approximately as fast as 3^n. We can also show that for n > 2:

```
T(n) = n + 2 * (sum of T(x) for x=0 to n-1)
T(n) = n + 2 * (T(0) + T(1) + ... + T(n-1))
T(n) = n + 2 * (T(0) + T(1) + ... + T(n-2)) + 2 * T(n-1)
T(n) = 1 +  n-1 + 2 * (T(0) + T(1) + ... + T(n-2))  +  2 * T(n-1)

# with
T(n-1) = n-1 + 2 * (sum of T(x) for x=0 to n-2)
T(n-1) = n-1 + 2 * (T(0) + T(1) + ... + T(n-2))

# we can substitute:
T(n) = 1 + T(n-1) + 2 * T(n-1)
T(n) = 1 + 3 * T(n-1)
```

So, if I'm not mistaken, the asymptotic time complexity should be in θ(3^n), or, allow me to make that joke, [even worse than O(no)](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/bark1r/alternative_big_o_notation/).

For Space complexity: Your function does not explicitly allocate any memory. So, there is only the constant overhead for recursing (assuming python does not optimize this out). The important aspect here is that the two recursion steps will happen one after the other, so that we get the recurrence:

```
S(0) = 1
S(n) = 1 + S(n-1)
```

which gives us a space complexity in θ(n).